# Trying to get the x, y coordinate of each random circle that is drawn on the screen

Tags: java, android, math, button, canvas

Hi im making a game that will create random circles on the screen. The circles created randomly will have the value red or green. My question is that i would like to be able to not only determine when a user clicks on one of the circles but determine what circle they have ultimately clicked on (red or green). Here is my code below. My main problem is trying to find the x and y of the circle that will be drawn

```
public class DrawingView extends View {



    public DrawingView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }
    RectF rectf = new RectF(0, 0, 200, 0);

    private static final int w = 100;
    public static int lastColor = Color.BLACK;
    private final Random random = new Random();
    private final Paint paint = new Paint();
    private final int radius = 230;
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    public static int redColor = Color.RED;
    public static int greenColor = Color.GREEN;
    int randomWidth =(int) (random.nextInt(Math.abs(getWidth()-radius/2)) + radius/2f);
    int randomHeight = (random.nextInt((int) Math.abs((getHeight()-radius/2 + radius/2f))));


    private final Runnable updateCircle = new Runnable() {
        @Override 
        public void run() {
            lastColor = random.nextInt(2) == 1 ? redColor : greenColor;
            paint.setColor(lastColor);
            invalidate();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);

        }
    };



    @Override 
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        handler.post(updateCircle);
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        handler.removeCallbacks(updateCircle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        // your other stuff here

        canvas.drawCircle(randomWidth, randomHeight + radius/2f, radius, paint);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event) {

        double r = Math.sqrt(((randomWidth^2)+(randomHeight^2)));
        int maxX = (int) (((randomWidth)*(randomWidth)) + r);
        int minX = (int) ((((randomWidth)*(randomWidth))) - r);
        int maxY = (int) (((randomHeight)*(randomHeight)) + r);
        int minY = (int) ((((randomHeight)*(randomHeight))) - r);

        public int xCoordinateOfRedColor(){
            if(redColor == lastColor){
                if(randomWidth > maxX && < minX){
                    event.getX();
                }
            };
        }
        public int yCoordinateOfRedColor(){
            if(redColor == lastColor){
                if(randomHeight > maxY && < minY){
                    event.getX();
                }
            };
        }
        if(redColor == lastColor){
            if(randomHeight > maxY && < minY){
                event.getY();
            }
        };
        if(greenColor == lastColor){

        };
        if(greenColor == lastColor){

        };

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN : 
                randomWidth = (int) event.getX();
                randomHeight = (int) event.getY();

                invalidate(); 
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP :


                break;
        }

        return true;

    }


}
```

I dont know if im close or really far away.

Comment: really no one can answer this? so sad

Comment: Chill.  I'm typing :P

Comment: haha sorry ive just been sitting on this problem for a very long time and im a little flustered. Take your time.

Comment: Please specify the problem more precisely. How many circles are supposed to displayed at once? Just one? Is its position supposed to keep changing? Do you want to keep adding more and more circles at different positions and display all of them on screen?

Comment: well in the handler class i am calling the method postDelayed and delaying one circle from being created on the screen every second.

Comment: I'm noticing that randomWidth/Height only change from their initial random values when the user clicks.  Then they take on the click's x and y values.  Thus the only random thing about the rest of the circles is their color.  This doesn't sound like what you said you wanted: "circles created randomly".

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to solve this kind of problem.  You can drive yourself nuts just trying to list them all.  One of the most powerful is to assign each shape a unique color when it is created.  Use that color to find the shape.  In other words...

When they click on this:

[image]

Sample the color from this:

[image]

Keep a hashmap from these unique colors to the shapes object reference.  Have all the shapes paint their unique color on a hidden bitmap that you never put on the screen.  When the user clicks, look up the color at that x y on the hidden bitmap.  Run that color thru the hashmap and you have a reference to the shape they clicked on.  Now you don't need to worry about overlaps or even using different shapes than circles.  This gives you not only the x and y of the shape but everything you know about that shape.

Of course for this to work you have to make your own class for the shapes.  I made the unique colors very distinct for illustration purposes.  In reality you could just have an int that you increment.  This could either be incremented by the constructor or better yet have a factory method inject it.

This is powerful enough that it works even when rendering 3D.  Just keep the visible and hidden bitmaps in sync.  That turns out to be easy since you just reuse the same rendering code.  Loop each shape and ask it to paint itself, with it's unique color, on a bitmap you hand to it.  Works as long as there are no additional effects that would change the color (shading, lighting, ray tracing).  Make sure to turn those off.

By the way, I don't think this:

```
if(randomHeight > maxY && < minY){
```

does what you think it does.  When I want to test that something is between two values I use:

```
if(minY <= randomHeight && randomHeight <= maxY){
```

because it reminds me of mathematical inequalities like 3 ≤ x ≤ 15.

Comment: this doesn't explain anything

Comment: This was an attempt to show you a way to reliably get the x and y of any circle they might click on.  Is that not what you were asking?

Comment: I think by "explain" they mean "contain code that does".

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I get your problem but what about keeping a list of the circles drawn (the last drawn at the beginning of the list) and when the user clicks somewhere you traverse the list and check every time whether the point clicked on the screen belongs to this circle ? The first time this happens will correspond to the last circle drawn that contains the clicked point.